# Symfony2 - form theming based on field name

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to create a `choice_widget_collapsed` theme, but only for one type of field, it can be checked by name, or by class name (it's entity field). Other choice field should be rendered by standard widget.
I've tried `FIELDNAME_widget`, `CLASSNAME_widget`, and I've searched in Google, but with no results.

**EDIT**

This is code of `choice_widget_colapsed`:

```
{% block choice_widget_collapsed -%}
    {% if required and empty_value is none and not empty_value_in_choices and not multiple %}
        {% set required = false %}
    {% endif %}
    <select {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if multiple %} multiple="multiple"{% endif %}>
        {% if empty_value is not none -%}
            <option value=""{% if required and value is empty %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ empty_value|trans({}, translation_domain) }}</option>
        {%- endif %}
        {%- if preferred_choices|length > 0 -%}
            {% set options = preferred_choices %}
            {{- block('choice_widget_options') -}}
            {% if choices|length > 0 and separator is not none -%}
                <option disabled="disabled">{{ separator }}</option>
            {%- endif %}
        {%- endif -%}
        {% set options = choices -%}
        {{- block('choice_widget_options') -}}
    </select>
{%- endblock choice_widget_collapsed %}
```

I want to modify HTML of this widget, only for fields named `color`.

Comment: Could you provide some code you've done, please? What's `choice_widget_collapsed` theme? Do you want to apply a specific theme on specific widget?

Comment: I've updated first post, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

When you want to change html of widget, based by field name, you have to overwrite block:

```
{% block _FORMNAME_FIELDNAME_widget -%}
    {# your html #}
{%- endblock %}
```